# Understanding REST Controllers Laravel

Tags: rest, controller, laravel-4

After studying online links, I've seen that they have this single route

`Route::controller('categories', 'CategoriesController');`

And then, by setting URL's in the forms of the blade templated views, I reach the functions of the controllers. Like `getSignup()` etc.

It's a basic question. How do these things work?

Thanks alot, have a nice day :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare your routes like this then a GET request to http://yoursite.com/categories will be routed to your CategoriesController's getIndex() method and a form POSTing to http://yoursite.com/categories/data (say) would be routed the postData() method.

You can build up more complex names by using hyphens in your routes. So POSTing to http://yoursite.com/categories/update-stuff would route to the controller's postUpdateStuff() method.

There's an explanation of this [in the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers). Though for most use cases I prefer to use the resource controllers that are explained immediately afterwards.